# A new bug is detected by Log Analytics Workspace

Tags: azure, azure-devops

A new bug is detected by Azure Log Analytics Workspace. How to send this event to Azure DevOps as a bug?

Comment: Give logic apps a try. I think it can connect the two.

Comment: Hi, have you tried maras's answer? It should work, if it helps, don't forget to [mark it as the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0iMP.png).

Answer (score 1):

As @JackPoint wrote, you can easily use for this Logic App. Ttere is a connector you can use:

[image]

Connector details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/

Of course you must decide how to trigger your Logic App.

Or you could just use AzDO REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1